# max-height on asp panel (div) inside td issues

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a table with 3 rows and 1 column each. In each  is an asp:panel control, which I believe is essentially rendered as a div. This div has max-height: 500, width: 100%; and overflow:scroll properties on it.

Problem is that whenever I try to load the page in IE8, it reverts to compatibility review as it cannot render it. If I remove max-height it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use "height" as well as "max-height" to make it work with IE. And also specify the unit, in this case "500px".

Comment: Thanks, that did stop the problem - however the height is constant which isn't really ideal, as there's a lot of whitespace if the contents does not fill up the div

Comment: You could use "_height", as only IE will use rules with an underscore. That way, it only looks odd in IE.